# Retrieving OS name

Tags: .net, version

Is there any way to get the OS name the user is currently using?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
System.Environment
```

class

```
Environment.OSVersion.ToString()
```

See **[Environment.OSVersion Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx)**

> Gets an OperatingSystem object that
>   contains the current platform
>   identifier and version number.

Comment: yeah!!! I'm aware of tat property. but how do i get the name of the OS..?? There is an API - win32_operatingsystem which gives me the OS name. But tat requires WMI service in runnin/stopped mode. Gettin error if the service is in paused state. So help me out wit a method to get the name of the OS if any.

Comment: Sadly, this was removed in `.NET Standard 1.6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) property.

```
Version version = Environment.OSVersion;
```

To decode the version, refer to the wikipedia page of [Microsoft Windows Timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows#Timeline_of_releases). For example, if the version is **6.1.7600**, then it is either a **Windows 7** or a **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

Note that there is no direct API to get the OS name, because a same version can refer to multiple public OS names.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the OS name directly. Instead use the `Environment.OSVersion.ToString(`) property to interpret the version & display the OS Name.

This [article](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29439-Getting-OS-Name-Windows-Vista-Windows.aspx) has a sample that will help you. It covers Win95 to Win7.

All you need to do is write a function that will return the OS name as shown in the above article.